# What is the best way for clustering data containing categorical and numeric variables with python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I need to cluster customers data that contains categorical and numerical features. numerical features are not on the same ranges (age, income....). I tried Mclust for numerical data after i have scaled it with StandardScale but that gave me intersected groups.

1-Should i normalize if with Standardscale results are not satisfying ?
2-what will be the best way to cluster with K-Prototype?
3-should clustering method should be dependent on the data distribution ?

I use pandas 
This is what i have used :

```
    #K-mean Cluster#search K
from scipy.spatial import distance as sci_distance
from sklearn import cluster as sk_cluster
cdata = data
K = range(1, 10)
KM = (sk_cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(cdata) for k in K)
centroids = (k.cluster_centers_ for k in KM)
D_k = (sci_distance.cdist(cdata, cent, 'euclidean') for cent in centroids)
dist = (np.min(D, axis=1) for D in D_k)
avgWithinSS = [sum(d) / cdata.shape[0] for d in dist]
plt.plot(K, avgWithinSS, 'b*-')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Average within-cluster sum of squares')
plt.title('Elbow for KMeans clustering')
plt.show()



#KMean Cluster
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, AgglomerativeClustering, 
AffinityPropagation #For clustering
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture #For GMM clustering
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                   # For graphics
import seaborn as sns
#Clustering
def doKmeans(X, nclust=3):
    model = KMeans(nclust)
    model.fit(X)
    clust_labels = model.predict(X)
    cent = model.cluster_centers_
    return (clust_labels, cent)

clust_labels, cent = doKmeans(data, 3)
kmeans = pd.DataFrame(clust_labels)
data.insert((data.shape[1]),'kmeans',kmeans)

#Plot the clusters obtained using k means
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
scatter = ax.scatter(data['var1'],data['var2'],
                     c=kmeans[0],s=50)
ax.set_title('K-Means Clustering')
ax.set_xlabel('var1')
ax.set_ylabel('var2')
plt.colorbar(scatter)
```

Comment: Are you working with pandas or dictionaries? Can we see anything you have already tried?

Comment: @MikePeder : I have added my code

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this the very wrong way.

Do **not** choose an approach just because you manage to get the code to run. This will never give you good results.

**First figure out *what* you need.** What is a cluster? What is a clustering (are all points in clusters? probably not. etc.)? What is a *good* clustering, and how can I measure this? Only then choose algorithms based on how well they match your requirements.

Otherwise, you will be solving the wrong problem.

Comment: i didnt choose this code randomly. I have a  good understanding of the objectif....i need to cluster data by different variables so i used kmeans but it didnt give separated groups !!!